# Trying to eliminate the initial ", " - string-formatting question

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm new to python (coding in general actually), a couple of days in.

I'm trying out this code:

```
name = input("What is your name:")
print("Hello", name + "!")

list_of_fruits = list(input("Enter multiple fruits you don't like :").split(", "))

print("I don't like the following fruits:", *list_of_fruits, sep=", ")
```

it returns this:

```
What is your name:Reg
Hello Reg!
Enter multiple fruits you don't like :apple, banana, orange
I don't like the following fruits:, apple, banana, orange
```

I'm trying to eliminate the "," after " I don't like the following fruits:" but I can't seem to find the right approach to this. It seems like the sep() function is added to the first string which is "I don't like the following fruit:". I can't seem to find my way around it. FYI I want to display the string with the list in one single line. Thanks!

This is the preferable result I'd like to achieve

```
I don't like the following fruits: apple, banana, orange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to comma-join a list of strings is with the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method.

```
print("I don't like the following fruits:", ', '.join(list_of_fruits))
```